# How to identify whether my login page is phished page or actual page?

Tags: login, phishing

how can i determine the difference between phished page and the normal web page?i knew about only one method **https** and **http** before the address will be one of the identification ..

is it there any other methods to find whether the  **login** page is phished?

any tool to notify me whether my page is phished or normal page?

Comment: You make sure the URL is the right one? (e.g. check if the URL is facebook.com and not facebook.some-strange-domain.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of browser extensions out there that can help with that.

One such for Chrome is [Anti-Phishing & Authenticity Checker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mggehmlfnempkheebgikhmemhnnpacle). This particular extension puts an icon in the address bar when you are actually at facebook.com, twitter.com, youtube.com or google.com.

There are quite a few others. Just search for "phishing" in the extension/add-on library for your favorite browser.

Comment: sir thanks it works,if you upload the links for firefox,ieand safari?it would be better,i can accept answer if you please update your post with it sir it may helpful for others